# Better way to compose test fixtures in ScalaTest

Tags: scala, composition, scalatest

We have test fixtures using [loan pattern](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#loanFixtureMethods). Leveraging this pattern to create "seed data" needed for a test to run. when test is dependent on data For e.g. following

```
"save definition" should {
"create a new record" in withSubject { implicit subject =>
  withDataSource { implicit datasource =>
    withFormType { implicit formtype =>

        val definitn = DefinitionModel(-1, datasource.id, formtype.id, subject.role.id, Some(properties))
    }
  }
}
```

Where `withSubject`, `withDataSource`, `withFormType` are test fixtures returning `subject`, `dataSource`, `formType` data respectively from database. `withDataSource` fixture requires `subject` implicitly. Building `DefinitionModel` requires `datasource.id` and `formtype.id`. so depending on the data requirement of a test calling such data builder fixtures is creating a lot of nested fixture situation. Is there a better way to "compose" /structure such fixtures?

Answer (score 5):

The answer given by @Nader Hadji Ghanbari still holds. I would just like to add that since version 3.x.x of scalatest the traits changed names. Copying from the migration guide:

> **Mixin traits that override withFixture**
>
> 4) In 3.0.0, the withFixture method has been moved from Suite to a new
>   trait, TestSuite. This was done to make room for a withFixture method
>   with a different signature in AsyncTestSuite. If you factored out a
>   withFixture method into a separate "suite mixin" trait, you'll need to
>   change "Suite" to "TestSuite" and "SuiteMixin" to "TestSuiteMixin".
>   For example, given this trait from 2.2.6:
>
> ```
> trait YourMixinTrait extends SuiteMixin { this: Suite =>
>  abstract override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest): Outcome = {
>    // ...
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> You will need to add the "Test" prefix, like this:
>
> ```
> trait YourMixinTrait extends TestSuiteMixin { this: TestSuite =>
>  abstract override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest): Outcome = {
>    // ...
>  }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this, the docs were confusing me. There's an open issue to get them updated - https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/issues/1207

Answer (score 4):

### Trait

[`trait`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/traits.html) is your friend. Composition is one of the requirements `trait`s cover very nicely.

### Composing traits

From [Scala Test Docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures#composingFixtures)

> #### Composing fixtures by stacking traits
>
> In larger projects, teams often end up with several different fixtures
>   that test classes need in different combinations, and possibly
>   initialized (and cleaned up) in different orders. A good way to
>   accomplish this in ScalaTest is to factor the individual fixtures into
>   traits that can be composed using the stackable trait pattern. This
>   can be done, for example, by placing withFixture methods in several
>   traits, each of which call super.withFixture.

For instance you can define the following `trait`s

```
trait Subject extends SuiteMixin { this: Suite =>

  val subject = "Some Subject"

  abstract override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {
    try super.withFixture(test) // To be stackable, must call super.withFixture
    // finally clear the context if necessary, clear buffers, close resources, etc.
  }
}

trait FormData extends SuiteMixin { this: Suite =>

  val formData = ...

  abstract override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = {
    try super.withFixture(test) // To be stackable, must call super.withFixture
    // finally clear the context if necessary, clear buffers, close resources, etc.
  }
}
```

Then you can bring this `trait`s to your test context by just mixing them in:

```
class ExampleSpec extends FlatSpec with FormData with Subject {

    "save definition" should {
        "create a new record" in {

            // use subject and formData here in the test logic            

        }
    }

}
```

### Stackable Traits

For more info on [Stackable Traits Pattern](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html) you can refer to [this article](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html)